# Running a Series of tests with uiautomator

Tags: java, android, android-uiautomator

I have a handful of test I have written all in separate classes. I would like them to all be tested in one continuos test, giving me one report. Thinking about it, I would use an intent to start the next class. But this isn't possible when extending `UiAuotomatorTestCase`. So, how would I do this? Or do I need to put them all in a single class and just execute that class? The only problem with that, is the class will start to get pretty big, and hard for me to stay organized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the command line, you need to use a comma to separate the classes and methods you want to run.

```
adb shell uiautomator runtest <NAME_OF_JAR>.jar -c <YOUR_CLASS>#<YOUR_FIRST_METHOD>, -c <YOUR_CLASS>#<YOUR_SECOND_METHOD>
```